# Is there any way to make scoreboard objectives Universal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

[1.10.2]

So I am making an adventure map and I made a money system that is a little bit glitchy. Basically, it works like this:

So first I would like to point out my scoreboard objectives:

- money > Dummy
- killedBasic > stat.killEntity.Zombie

And I have one repeating command block (Always Active) with the following command:

```
/testfor @a[score_killedBasic_min=1]
```

And I have two comparators wired out of the repeating command block as so:

[image: Full command block setup]

The "Resets killedBasic" command block has this command:

```
/scoreboard players set @a killedBasic 0
```

And the "Adds 10 to money" command block has the following command:

```
/scoreboard players add @a money 10
```

The system itself works fine but I noticed that if say there were two players on the adventure map then if one killed a Zombie they would both get 10 "money" which looked messy.

So my question is (yeah **tl;dr** I know) is it possible to maybe a scoreboard operate on its own without a player name beside the score? And also is it possible to use renamed entity's such as rabbits to add the score (money) to the scoreboard?

Comment: Just to be clear: the "money" objective is used by *all* players as a shared pool of money? Each player is not meant to have their own amount of money?

Comment: Well at first it was the latter but now I think sharing a pool gives a more adventurous spirit to it. @Skylinerw < if that's unclear THE POOL THE POOL!!!

Comment: If THE POOL is not possible then I will go with each having their own amount as long as it stays under 60 command blocks ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use a selector for a playerscore. You can use any name you want, even if it's not a valid player's name. For instance, the following sets the score of a fake player named "pool":

```
/scoreboard players add pool money 10
```

Do keep in mind that if a player named "pool" joins, they will essentially "own" that score. You'd want to be careful when manipulating the scores in case their existence causes a conflict (such as running `/scoreboard players add @a money 10`). If you prepend the name with "#" (such as "#pool"), the name will not appear on the sidebar and also prevents naming conflicts because real players cannot have the "#" character in their name.

---

As for your mechanism, you'll want to use Chain command blocks, which directly specifies activation order, instead of comparators, which does not have a guaranteed activation order and causes delay. The delay can cause the mechanism to lock up if a player kills a zombie before the comparator turns off.

`/testfor` is not particularly useful, especially in multiplayer situations. You can replace it with a scoreboard operation that would account for multiple kills in the same tick, rather than assuming there is only 1 kill amongst all players.

Image example of the mechanism:

[image: Repeating Block (1) > Chain Block (2)]

Commands:

1. Increment the fake "#pool" player's score equal to all playerscores for the "killedBasic" objective (or change "#pool" to a name you would prefer, removing "#" so that it appears on the sidebar).

   ```
   /scoreboard players operation #pool money += @a[score_killedBasic_min=1] killedBasic
   ```
2. Set playerscores for "killedBasic" to 0 like usual.

   ```
   /scoreboard players set @a[score_killedBasic_min=1] killedBasic 0
   ```

This is a multiplayer-friendly and multi-kill friendly solution that will not lock up if multiple kills are made in subsequent ticks.

Comment: O_O........ Wow

Comment: What does operation do? I obviously haven't learnt enough about scoreboard objectives. They seem to have quite a big influence over stuff nowadays ;)

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket The wiki has a lengthy description of scoreboard operations here: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Scoreboard#Players_commands

Comment: Thanks. Been rooting around on YouTube for something along these lines . ;)